# Get error message from Oracle exception using python and cx_oracle

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

The problem: I need to get error message from oracle database exception, but I don't know how.

Example:

```
try:
   ...
   cursor.execute("<SOME SQL>")
except DatabaseError, e:
   error, = e.args
   print e.message
```

This code outputs something like:

```
ORA-20000: Some error description
ORA-06512: at "GEN.ERR", line 3
ORA-06512: at "SCHEME_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME", line 49
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

So, how can I get only error description ("Some error description") in the above example, but not the full error message with table names etc. ? I know that I can parse this output but I think there should be more clever way to get the error message.

Thanks.

Comment: `<some sql>` isn't really good enough here. Show us real code and real errors please.